# SQL - Updating table rows based on anothers table content

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a temp table named #tempTab1 that contains such column as:

```
UserId, GroupId, Quantity
```

then I have another table #tempTab2 that has similar columns:

```
IdUser, IdGroup, ItemQuantity
```

I want to update the first's table Quantity column using the data from the second's table ItemQuantity column.

I've tried doing it using the following query:

```
UPDATE #tempTab1
SET #tempTab1.Quantity = #tempTab2.ItemQuantity
WHERE #tempTab1.UserId = #tempTab2.IdUser 
  AND #tempTab1.GroupId = #tempTab2.IdGroup
```

and what I get is

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Whats the best way to deal with it? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE t1
   SET Quantity = t2.ItemQuantity
FROM #tempTab1 t1 JOIN
     #tempTab2
     ON t1.UserId = t2.IdUser AND t1.GroupId = t2.IdGroup;
```